# Formula not copying correctly using VB - with full code

Tags: excel, vba

Both "Peter's" helped me out with this one previously but I couldn't add the full code to my comment.

Issue is:  When I add ".FormulaR1C1 to the code below I get an error message as "Object required".  It works without the ".FormulaR1C1 but that creates a problem in the actual formula.

The Code

Sheets(gcsCombinedSheetName).Cells(lngLastRow, columnletter).FormulaR1C1 = getConfigPosition.Offset(0, 2).Formula.R1C1

Full code

```
Sub Pricing_format()

Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngLastRow2 As Long
Dim Fundcolumn As Long
Dim rngToCheck As Range
Dim columnletter As String
Dim columnheader As String
Dim ActuateColumn As Long
Dim getConfigPosition As Range
Dim counter As Long
Dim getFormula As Variant
Dim Wk As Worksheet
Dim WB As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Set gRwksconfigeration = Sheets(gcsConfigSheetName)
gRnCT_FieldSearch_Brks = gRwksconfigeration.Range(CT_FieldSearch_Brks)
gRnCT_Fieldsearch_SecurID = gRwksconfigeration.Range(CT_FieldSearch_SecurID)
gRnCT_FieldSearch_BrokerFactor = gRwksconfigeration.Range(CT_FieldSearch_BrokerFactor)
gRnCT_Required_Col = gRwksconfigeration.Range(CT_Required_Col)
gRnCT_File_Loc = gRwksconfigeration.Range(CT_File_Loc)
gsInputFileName = Dir(gRnCT_File_Loc)

counter = 1

Set gwkscurrent = ActiveWorkbook

    With Sheets(gcsCombinedSheetName)
        .Cells.Clear
    End With

    Do

        lngLastRow2 = FindLastRow(gwkscurrent.Sheets(gcsCombinedSheetName).Name)

        'On Error GoTo OpenError
            Set gwkbInputdata = Workbooks.Open(gRnCT_File_Loc & gsInputFileName)
        'On Error GoTo 0

        With Sheets(1)

            Fundcolumn = Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:=gRnCT_Fieldsearch_SecurID, after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns).Column
            lngLastRow = FindLastRow(Sheets(1).Name)

                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) > 0 Then

                    Set rngToCheck = Range(.Cells(1, Fundcolumn), .Cells(lngLastRow, Fundcolumn))

                    If rngToCheck.Count > 1 Then

                            On Error Resume Next
                            rngToCheck.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                            On Error GoTo 0
                        Else
                            If VBA.IsEmpty(rngToCheck) Then rngToCheck.EntireRow.Delete
                    End If

                End If

                On Error Resume Next
                    .Cells.Find(What:=gRnCT_FieldSearch_Brks, after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues _
                        , LookAt:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                On Error GoTo 0

                On Error Resume Next
                    .Cells.Find(What:=gRnCT_FieldSearch_BrokerFactor, after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues _
                        , LookAt:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                On Error GoTo 0

             lngLastRow = FindLastRow(Sheets(1).Name)

            Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngLastRow, 1)).EntireRow.Copy gwkscurrent.Sheets(gcsCombinedSheetName).Cells(lngLastRow2 + 1, 1)

            ActiveWorkbook.Close False

        End With

        gsInputFileName = Dir

    Loop Until gsInputFileName = vbNullString



    Set getConfigPosition = Sheets(gcsConfigSheetName).Cells.Find(What:=gRnCT_Required_Col, after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
            xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(counter, 0)

    Do

        columnletter = getConfigPosition
        columnheader = getConfigPosition.Offset(0, 1)
        getFormula = getConfigPosition.Offset(0, 2)


            lngLastRow = FindLastRow(gcsCombinedSheetName)

            Sheets(gcsCombinedSheetName).Cells(lngLastRow, columnletter).FormulaR1C1 = getConfigPosition.Offset(0, 2).Formula.R1C1
            Sheets(gcsCombinedSheetName).Cells(2, columnletter) = getConfigPosition.Offset(0, 1)

            With Sheets(gcsCombinedSheetName)
               .Cells(lngLastRow, columnletter).Copy Range(.Cells(lngLastRow, columnletter), .Cells(3, columnletter))
            End With

            counter = counter + 1

            Set getConfigPosition = Sheets(gcsConfigSheetName).Cells.Find(What:=gRnCT_Required_Col, after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
                    xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:= _
                    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(counter, 0)


    Loop Until getConfigPosition = ""

    With Sheets(gcsCombinedSheetName).Rows("2:2")
                    .Font.Bold = True
                    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

    MsgBox ("Macro Complete")
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few comments:

- To solve your issue, replace `Formula.R1C1`with `FormulaR1C1`
- Your indentation is strange. There is no need for example to indent in line `lngLastRow = FindLastRow(gcsCombinedSheetName)`. Usually you only indent when there is a "subcode block", e.g. in a `For` loop, an `If`statement, etc.
- Use `With` only when you access multiple properties of an object.

  ```
  With Sheets(gcsCombinedSheetName)
      .Cells.Clear
  End With
  ```

  can be replaced with `Sheets(gcsCombinedSheetName).Cells.Clear`
- Consider using `Range.Resize` instead of `Range(Cell1, Cell2))` - quite often the former is much easier

Last but not least: You can edit questions in SO, so no need to open a new one! :-)

Comment: Thank you for all the advise and your comments are (as always) welcome and very helpful.  I need to get the hang of ".resize" and start using more often.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  When I used RC [ ] referencing in the formula and just used ".formula" and not ".formulaR1C1" it works.  It goes against the logic I understand but it worked.  I would like to Thank "Peter A" & "Peter L" for their continued support.  Thanks lads.